# Run access query from Excel and pass parameters to the query

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

How to execute a query in MS Access db from Excel VBA code or macro.
MS-Access query accepts some parameters, that needs to be passed from Excel.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String

strFile = "C:\docs\Test.mdb"

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile

''Late binding, so no reference is needed
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "INSERT INTO ATable (AField) " _
& "VALUES (" & Sheet1.[A1] & ")"

cn.Execute strSQL

cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

You can also refer in-line in the sql to a dataset from Excel.

EDIT re comments

Using a command:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM ATable " _
& "WHERE AField = @AField"

With cmd
    Set .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandText = strSQL
    .CommandType = 1 'adCmdText

    ''ADO Datatypes are often very particular
    ''adSmallInt = 2 ; adParamInput = 1
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@AField", 2, 1, , Sheet1.[A1])

End With
Set rs = cmd.Execute
```

See also: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181782

Comment: He Remou, Thanks for you reply. I need to execute the ms-access query and get result. Your sample gives inputs for connecting to the db and save data. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This uses ADODB.

```
Set m_Connection = New Connection

If Application.Version = "12.0" Then
    m_Connection.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
Else
    m_Connection.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
End If

m_Connection.Open <full path to Access DB>
If m_Connection.State > 0 Then

    Dim rsSource As New Recordset
    rsSource.Open strQuery, m_Connection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

    Dim result As Long
    Dim rngTarget As Range
    rngTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(m_SheetName).Range("A1")

    If Not rsSource.BOF Then
        result = rngTarget.CopyFromRecordset(rsSource)
    End If

    If rsSource.State Then rsSource.Close
    Set rsSource = Nothing

End If
```

So it runs the query and puts it where you like. strQuery is the name of a query in the db or an SQL string.