# Using INSERT INTO to write data into access database

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to use the INSERT INTO command to write data into an Access 2007 file from a excel 2010 file. The data is contained in the "NewProj" worksheet in the Tool_Selector.xlsm excel file and it needs to be written to the "Tool_Database.mdb" file but unfortunately I have received several different errors.. This is what I currently have

```
Sub AddData()
  Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
  Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection

  Cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Tools_Dev\_Tool_Selector\Tool_Selector.xlsm;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;" _
        & "Persist Security Info=False"

  Cn.Execute "INSERT INTO Project_Names IN 'D:\Tool_Database\Tool_Database.mdb' SELECT * FROM Worksheets("NewProj").Range("A2").Value"

  Cn.Close
  Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

I got the code from this thread: [Insert Data from Excel into Access using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226004/insert-data-from-excel-into-access-using-vba)

I just need to transfer the value of individual cells.

Thanks.

Comment: I know that this
Cn.Execute "INSERT INTO Project_Names IN 'D:\Tool_Database\Tool_Database.mdb' SELECT * FROM Worksheets("NewProj").Range("A2").Value"

is where is breaks... How can I select a specific cell or row of cells?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122582/run-access-query-from-excel-and-pass-paramerts-to-the-query/5122667#5122667

Comment: phenomenal, you're a good person.

Comment: When I run that code, I get runtime error 424 Object Required 
On this line:
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Project_Names (Proj_Num) " & "VALUES (" & NewProj.[A1] & ")"

Comment: What happens when you type `?NewProj.[A1]` into the immediate window? I think you must have this reference wrong. You can also check by subsistuting a value, eg, `VALUES (1)`, if this is okay, you can be fairly sure it is your Excel reference that is wrong.

Comment: @TylerHarrington Do you have the option available to do this in reverse and use Access to read the Excel file, if so I always preferred this method as you can go cell by cell if need be and it's also a little easier to capture errors. If you can then i'll post the required code.

Comment: Matt, the way my project works is as follow: A user clicks a button to open a form. The user then fills the form out and this information is sent to the database. To me, it doesn't seem logical/possible to do it from Access because how will Access know when a user has filled out the form? I am new to Excel though so I could be wrong. Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: @Remou When I added the ? I get a compile error. The error certainly is a reference error because I tried the Values (1) as you said and it worked. The form that I am using isn't in the same worksheet as the table which holds the data to be stored to excel. As I said to Matt, a user clicks a button on the main sheet and a form opens, fill in the form and hit submit. The data is stored in a seperate sheet. How can I refer to that cell? Sorry I am such an amateur with Excel... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you know what the immediate window is? You do not put ?Etc in the code but in the immediate window. What is the name of the sheet with the cell that you want to refer to? Is it the same workbook as the form? Note, workbook, not worksheet.

Comment: Yes it is in the same workbook. The sheet of the cell I want to store is called NewProj

Comment: I am not sure what the immediate window is... Where exactly does the ?NewProj.[A1] go?

Comment: Ah I see, when I entered ?NewProj.[A1] in the immediate window, an error came up with Object Required...

Comment: Try `?worksheets("newproj").[a1]` I do not think you can refer to a worksheet by name as you have done. If that works, you can use that in oace of the existing reference, without the question mark, of course. BTW in Stackoverflow, if you prefix a person's name with @, they will get a message, otherwise they may miss it, unless they are the author of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using VBA code IN the SQL statement. The following line will compile but fail upon execution:

```
Cn.Execute "INSERT INTO Project_Names IN 'D:\Tool_Database\Tool_Database.mdb' SELECT * FROM Worksheets("NewProj").Range("A2").Value"
```

It fails because you're still in the SELECT statement when you make use the VBA functions of Worksheets(), .Range, and .Value. IIRC, you should be able to use SQL syntax to select a particular range from a sheet. The proper syntax for that should be:

```
"SELECT * FROM [Sheet$]"
```

If you want a particular range then you'd try:

```
"SELECT * FROM [Sheet$A1:C20]"
```

There's a Microsoft article on this at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819 if you're looking for more information on using ADO with Excel. The Scripting Guys also wrote a decent article that helped me understand it a few years back: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx.

Hopefully that helps you solve your problem. However, I will leave you with one word of warning. I remember running into some really weird issues when querying an already open Excel spreadsheet when I was first using this code. If I was querying an Excel spreadsheet that was already open then I would run into an issue where memory would be leaked and Excel would eventually run out of memory to use. The only way to solve the problem was to close Excel entirely. It also didn't matter whether the ADO references were properly closed/cleared or not.

In fact, I just Googled it to double check and here's an article on the bug: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;319998&Product=xlw.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds similar to a problem I once had when upgrading from office 2003 to 2007.

My solution was changing the provider in the connection string. Since you're using a modern office version I think it should be:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;
```

You might want to look into that Extended property as well. I know that Excel 8.0 is a Excel '97 file. And Excel 2010 is 14.0