# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Current Recordset does not support updating error received when trying to update access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vbscript, ms-access-2007, adodb

I have a ASP page where a user will upload a excel file. After the file is successfully uploaded I want to take the rows in the REGION tab and insert them into an MS Access 2007 table. Below is the code I used and I am getting this error. Can I use the recordset update with the Microsoft.ACE.OLEB.12.0 provider? Is there a better way to do this?
ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cb3'

Current Recordset does not support updating. This may be a limitation of the provider, or of the selected locktype.

```
Set cnnExcel = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnnExcel.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & strExcelFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=" &  Chr(34) & "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1" & Chr(34) & ";" 
Response.Write "Excel connection opened<BR>"

' Load ADO Recordset with Excel Data
Set rstExcel = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rstExcel.Open "Select * from [REGION$]", cnnExcel, adOpenStatic 
Response.Write "Excel Recordset loaded<BR>"

' Open Access Connection
Set cnnAccess = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnnAccess.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strAccessFile & ";Persist Security Info=False;" 
Response.Write "Access connection opened<BR>"
Const adOpenStatic = 1
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H0001
' Load ADO Recordset with Access Data
Set rstAccess = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rstAccess.Open "REGION", cnnAccess, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
Response.Write "Access Recordset loaded<BR>"

' Synchronize Recordsets and Batch Update
Do Until rstExcel.EOF

        ' .AddNew
        For each field in rstExcel.Fields
            If field.Name = "% Over/Under" Then
                rstAccess.AddNew field.Name,0
            Else
                rstAccess.AddNew field.Name,field.Value
            End If
        Next

    rstExcel.MoveNext
Loop
rstAccess.UpdateBatch
```

Comment: I have just noticed that you have "server". Have you checked the permissions on the folder?

Comment: Also, is it your intention that you should have a new record for each field? If not, you need one AddNew, the field loop and an update. What ever you do, get rid of BatchUpdate. I do not believe it is doing what you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you Hans, Tim and Remou. I followed this example [Using INSERT INTO to write data into access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103867/using-insert-into-to-write-data-into-access-database)

```
  ' Open Access Connection
Set cnnAccess = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnnAccess.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strAccessFilePath & ";Persist Security Info=False;"   
cnnAccess.Execute "DELETE * FROM REGION"
'Open Excel Connection
Set cnnExcel = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnnExcel.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & strExcelFilePath & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=" &  Chr(34) & "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1" & Chr(34) & ";" 
Response.Write "Excel connection opened<BR>"
cnnExcel.Execute "INSERT INTO REGION IN 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FolderName\App_Data\AccessFileName.accdb' " & _
                "Select col1,col2,col3,col4" & _
               "from [REGION$]"


' Clean up    
cnnExcel.Close
Set cnnExcel = Nothing
cnnAccess.Close
Set cnnAccess = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a different cursor type - adOpenStatic doesn't support updates.

http://www.w3schools.com/ado/prop_rs_cursortype.asp

Comment: Yes. However, it still will not work properly with that loop, which add a new record for every field and will fall over on `rstAccess.UpdateBatch` because the records are alreadt added.

Comment: Agreed - there are potentially other problems there. As you note, you don't need update batch, if you use the parameterized version of AddNew.

Answer (score 1):

You said "*... I want to take the rows in the REGION tab and insert them into an MS Access 2007 table*".

Although I don't fully understand your sample code, you seem to be opening one recordset for the Access table and another for the Excel worksheet, then moving through the Excel recordset and inserting (*something* for) each row into the Access recordset.

If the Access recordset was editable (ie not read-only), you could insert *something*.  However, even if you got it working, you would still be left with a RBAR (Row By Agonizing Row) approach.  It would be better to use a set-based approach so you import all the worksheet rows as a single operation.

Here is an Access query which mimics what I think you're trying to do.  My `Region` worksheet has 4 columns of data: `% Over/Under`; `fld2`; `fld3`; and `fld4`.  The Access `REGION` table has those same 4 columns set up with compatible data types.

```
INSERT INTO REGION ( [% Over/Under], fld2, fld3, fld4 )
SELECT 0 AS [% Over/Under], fld2, fld3, fld4
FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;DATABASE=C:\share\Access\regions.xlsx].[Region$];
```

If you can get a similar query working in your Access database, change your ASP to open the ADO connection to your Access db, then use the connection to `Execute` your `INSERT` statement.  Your ASP code would be much simpler than what you have now, and should operate considerably faster.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103867/using-insert-into-to-write-data-into-access-database

Comment: Hans for some reason I can only do 1 upvote. How do I give more because I wouldn't have explored the INSERT if you had not suggested it.

Comment: You can only upvote an answer once.  I am glad my suggestion was helpful, and thank you for your vote.  One vote is fine.  :-)