# Get parameter input from user in Excel query

Tags: sql, ms-access, parameters, excel-2007

I have my database in .mdb file and i want to query the data using select query  and the result displayed in excel spread sheet(using Get external data menu) but i need to query the records and show the result based on the input(in where condition) entered by user in specific cells(4 fields). Sometimes i use one or two fields in where condition or sometimes i use 3 fields in where conditions to select the records but the remaining fields will be left blank.

I can write query when the user enter values in all the four fields without leaving blank in any field but i need query for either case of searching.

SELECT * FROM `P:\Indexing\Data\Services_Indexed_data.mdb`.GAS S_CARD WHERE (S_CARD.HOUSE_NO=?) AND (S_CARD.STREET_NAME=?) AND (S_CARD.SUFFIX=?) AND (S_CARD.FILE_NAME=?) AND (S_CARD.CITY=?)

"?" will be filled when i select the input cell as a parameters from user. Also i need query with LIKE operator in where conditions. Please let me know how to write the query for this.

Comment: Is that a valid SQL string? Are you using a database connection? You might try reviewing [this](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/running-an-access-parameter-query-from-excel/) and understanding how to connect to Access from Excel, where to build the original parameter query, and passing the values for those parameters from Excel to Access.

Comment: Yes, Its a valid SQL query. Its working fine when i use two/three where conditions with AND/OR operator but i need query for either case like if i left blank any field then the query should return the values based on the valid parameters(conditions) and it not to be considered the blank fields from where conditions. No, i directly connected the mdb file from folders.

Answer (score 0):

**Reference:** I used the MS Query external connection from Excel to link to my .accdb file (I know that's not the same as your's but it shouldn't make a big difference). I then opened the External Data Properties menu and clicked on the button to the right of the Connection name to open the Connection Properties window. I navigated to the Definition tab and selected the Parameters button at the bottom and used the "Get the value from the following cell" option to reference the input cell.

However, I also can't figure out how to have Excel create a dynamic WHERE clause based on whether your parameter reference cells are null.

**Solution:**
I would recommend building a parameter query in Access and expanding your WHERE clause to account for each permutation of Null values in the parameters. This will be a huge string, that is difficult to read and format, but should be manageable in Access's GUI. For example, using only two of your parameters for HOUSE_NO and STREET_NAME (data types may be incorrect):

```
PARAMETERS [HOUSE_NO] Text (255), [STREET_NAME] Text (255);
SELECT * FROM S_CARD
WHERE (([HOUSE_NO] Is Not Null) AND (S.CARD.HOUSE_NO Like [HOUSE_NO])
  AND ([STREET_NAME] Is Not Null) AND (S.Card.STREET_NAME Like [STREET_NAME]))
OR (([HOUSE_NO] Is Null) AND ([STREET_NAME] Is Not Null) 
  AND (S.Card.STREET_NAME Like [STREET_NAME]))
OR (([HOUSE_NO] Is Not Null) AND (S.Card.HOUSE_NO Like [HOUSE_NO])
  AND ([STREET_NAME Is Null))
OR (([HOUSE_NO] Is Null) AND ([STREET_NAME] Is Null));
```

You would need to make an `OR` for each permutation of parameters that are left blank, and how the query should return those results. You would then need to write a VBA procedure to connect to Access, open the parameter query, pass the parameters, execute the query, and export to your excel file. It's a lot more work. For help, you can see part of the process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122582/run-access-query-from-excel-and-pass-paramerts-to-the-query) but it deals with action queries instead of select and does not copy to excel.

Because Excel doesn't seem to name the parameters, there doesn't seem to be a way to test whether the input cells are blank and adjust the WHERE clause accordingly. When I tried using the names from the Parameters menu in Excel `[PARAMETER 1]` and `[PARAMETER 2]` in the command text on the definition tab, it ended up creating new Parameters (#3, #4).

This is a good question though and I'd suggest waiting for another user to weigh in, we may get lucky.